# Javascript/jquery : retain option item of select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, dhtml

I have select box

```
<select id="abc">
<option value="1">xyz</option>
<option value="2">pqr</option>
</select>
```

Through third party javascript, it is removing all options

```
document.getElementById("abc").options.length=1; // third party code
```

Now how do i retain those options again ,as i can see them in the browser page source. How to do this through javascript/jquery? is this possible? can someone help.

Thanks

Comment: If third party code is removing your options, you must either (a) re-add the items or (b) remove or prevent that particular line of code from working.

Comment: (b)preventing 3rd party code is not in my hand,  (a) will go with this, but how can i restore 'page source' option to empty select box through javascript.   thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store a clone of those options. With this:

```
window.$clonedOptions = $("#abc option").clone(); //Saves option clones
```

Then, to restore them, you can do:

```
$("#abc").empty().append(window.$clonedOptions);
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

What you see in the browser view source is the one that is generated at the time of page load and not the one that is generated dynamic (by javascript).

Please inspect the select box using FireBug and check whether there are options or not.

If you don't have any options then you won't be able to do that.